# Console doesn’t update when I refresh server, console log does not reflect changes in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

When I change the code in my file the server doesn't seem to update according to my new code. For example, I'll type console.log('Testing if update work') but the console will show my previous message of 'work'. Some tests I've done are below.

Test 1: Hit the green refresh button
failed to change

Test 2: Exit VSC, reopen from Powershell (with code .), turn on the server, npm run start-local in terminal          WORKED - Temporary Fix

Test 3: npm run start-local again
Failed

So far the only way I've found to update my code is by exiting VSC and going through PowerShell and reopening VSC. I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this and expedite the process of updating my code.

Thanks :)

Comment: You didn't share any details. Even, whether it's the frontend or the backend that doesn't refresh, and what the `start-local` is.

Comment: Might be a permissions issue with the directory you're trying to run your code from. Could also try running with `ng s --poll 2000`

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when coding in laptop (usually I use PC). On Visual Studio Code, go to File and setting Save for autoSave. I hope it works for you.